# Ordenar menu por ID

Tags: sql

Tenho um menu gerenciável, onde será necessário organizar os itens por ID. Cada item do menu, corresponde à um ID.

```
$rsm = exesql('SELECT * FROM produtos_categorias WHERE id_pai = 0 AND ativo = "S" ORDER BY categoria ASC')
```

Essa é a organização que possuo. Ele está organizando por categoria. Como eu faria para organizar por ID, onde eu possa selecionar os IDs específicos?

Tentei `ORDER BY ID[1,2,4,8]` e não deu certo.

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Answer (score 0):

Lógica de ordenação é diferente de lógica de seleção. Se você precisa ordenar pelo `id`, então basta fazer `ORDER BY id [DESC]` - onde `DESC` é opcional, presente apenas quando desejar ordenar de forma decrescente. Já, se você precisa selecionar apenas alguns dos ids, você deve fazer isso no `where`. Acredito que sua consulta deveria ficar assim:

```
SELECT * 
FROM produtos_categorias 
WHERE id_pai = 0 
AND ativo = "S" 
AND id IN (1,2,4,8)
ORDER BY id ASC
```